# How to fix the web.config connection string which always default to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I am using VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2. My challenge is how to fix the `web.config` which has default `SQLEXPRESS`.

My database is on SQL Server 2008 R2. I would like my connection string to point to SQL Server R2. This server is on my local machine however `SQLEXPRESS` was installed when I installed VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `SqlExpress` your connection string looks like:

```
Data Source=.\SqlExpress
```

Replace it with:

```
Data Source=localhost
```

If your instance has a name (not the default instance, you need to define it in setup):

```
Data Source=localhost\instanceName
```